# How to get back String as a response using retrofit?

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit

i have tried by calling

```
String s=findDate();
```

this findDate() is declared in retrofit service as

```
public RetrofitService{
@GET(/findDate)
String findDate()
}
```

Is this correct?

But i am getting response as a string 214-11-24 when i tried using Async Callback. Why it is so? The server is returning date as a string like 2014-11-24

Comment: Please clarify your question.. "I'm getting" what? And please show your async retrofit interface.

Comment: GreyBeardedGeek, i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

To use Retrofit asynchronoisly, you must declare the method in the interface with an extra Callback parameter as the last parameter.

Retrofit will then operate asynchronously, and invoke your Callback when the data is available.

If you do not declare the method with a Callback, it operates synchronously.

Comment: yes i have tried using Callback, it's working. But i want without using callback.

Comment: You can either use it with a callback async, or without a callback sync, and that seems to be working for you as expected. What else are you looking for?

Comment: String s=findDate(); it is giving me retrofit error. But findDate(new Callback<String>){}; is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think must be 

    `public interface RetrofitService(){
        @GET(/findDate) 
        String findDate()
    }`

and maybe you could share the `RestAdapter` object

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. I use retrofit:2.1.0.

Api interface:

```
public interface APIService {
@GET("api/get_info")
    Call<ResponseBody> getInfo();//import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
}
```

Api call:

```
// Retrofit service creation code skipped here
String json = retrofitService().getInfo().execute().body().string();
```